# How to parse a hex value that is represented by signed 8.8 fixed-point notation? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, fixed-point, eddystone

I would like to parse a two-byte value that is "expressed in a signed 8.8 fixed-point notation". Let's assume that I have the two bytes in the hexadecimal format below.

```
let data = '1800';
```

The `0x1800` in hexadecimal 8.8 fixed point notation should be 24 when converted.

Another example: `0x8000` in hexadecimal signed 8.8 fixed point notation should be -128 when converted.

#### More details

I'm specifically attempting to parse the temperature from an Eddystone Telemetry frame, which is defined here: https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/eddystone-tlm/tlm-plain.md#field-notes

Comment: Have you checked out [the documentation for the `parseInt()` function?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Also `0x18` is 24, not 27.

Comment: Did you mean to tag javascript? Vanilla JS doesn't have types identifiers like that. If you're using a different language it'd probably be the equivalent of: `parseInt(data, 16) / 256`

Comment: @Khauri I did. Thanks for pointing that out, updated.

Comment: Hi @Khauri This looks mostly right with one exception. Since it's signed 8.8 fixed point notation, it needs to handle potentially negative numbers. Specifically the value can range between 128 and -128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a prototype from a custom object. Like this:

```
function FixedPoint(fraction){
  this.fraction = fraction;
}

FixedPoint.prototype.calculate = function(value){
  let intValue = parseInt(value, 16);
  let signed = (intValue & 0x8000) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
  return signed * intValue / Math.pow(2, this.fraction);
}
```

How to use it?

```
let example = new FixedPoint(8);
example.calculate('1840');
```

returns 24.25

More info about [fixed point here](http://www.hugi.scene.org/online/coding/hugi%2015%20-%20cmtadfix.htm)

Comment: This works for most cases. Since I want to handle *signed* 8.8 fixed point notation, how might I update the calculate function to handle, for example, '8000' evaluating to -128? I'll update the question with this example for clarity.

Comment: @claytonkucera Can you link to more documentation of this format? How is the fractional part handled when the number is negative?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I'm working off of the Eddystone Telemetry Spec provided here: https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/eddystone-tlm/tlm-plain.md#field-notes . The spec does not clarify how the fractional part is meant to be handled when the number is negative.

Comment: Sure @claytonkucera. I updated the answer to solve hex signed numbers.

Comment: @Bergi What are the different ways the fractional part can be handled in the case of a signed fixed point notation? Is it a question of whether or not the fraction bits are reduced (from 8 to 7) to fit the sign bit?

Comment: @claytonkucera It probably refers to http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/index_fixed_point.html. And really means that it's just a signed 16 bit integer, in units of 1/256.

Comment: I don't think your handling of the sign bit is correct. I'm still not entirely sure whether the data bits should use two's complement (like @Ry's answer does), but even if they don't you need to use `intvalue & 0x7FFF` in the final line.

Comment: @claytonkucera From what I've seen, it's always the integer part that is reduced by one bit to allow for the sign representation.

Comment: My updated answer just was to illustrate how to do it quick and easy. Maybe you need a more complex or robust answer. In that case, you can use inspiration from current answers. I expect this help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can shift the value left so that its sign bit lines up with JavaScript’s 32-bit signed integers:

```
let data = 0x8000;  // = parseInt('8000', 16);
data << 16          // -2147483648
```

Then divide that so the high byte represents 0–255:

```
(data << 16) / (1 << 24)  // -128
```